# Is it possible to embed c# into a microcontroller

Tags: c#, microcontroller

I need to switch off the light from a command from the pc. Is this possible using c#?

Does microcontroller recognize c# code?

Comment: is possible if you have .net framework on it.

Comment: meadow f7 also uses C# as native language
https://www.wildernesslabs.co/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the way you asked the question, it seams that you are not much familiar with writing microcontrollers software. Although .NET Micro Framework exists for them and C# is supported, the general concept of microcontroller programming is quite different compared to desktop application programming. Unless you are willing to spend some time to study microcontrollers, I would recommend you to use some USB relay board instead and control relay directly from your desktop C# application where you feel like home.

You can take a look at [**this**](http://www.quancom.de/quancom/quancom01.nsf/eng/pb/USBREL8.htm!OpenDocument&Click=) board which has C# examples, or take a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863621/controlling-a-form-c-relay-in-c) SOF topic where similar topic was discussed.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for one, the [Netduino](http://netduino.com/) is an Arduino-like board with .NET Micro Framework support integrated, and could definitely do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can send some events to the ports (e.g: serial.port)
from c sharp by button event but you have to use : using System.IO.Ports  This is applied after making the real work programming in c language using for example mikroC OR any other